# React Naitve i18n ，how to translate the content of useState()?

Tags: react-native

I met an issue ,my idea is ,when click a botton ,the text from "Hello,click me " change to "thank you " ,and I need to translate them into another language ,such as Chinese ..

However ,it can't work  ... Any one can help pleaseeee ! Thank you so much !!

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View,Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import i18n from './../translations/i18n';

function TryBtn(props) {
    const[text,setText] =useState({i18n.t('user_detail.click_me')});
    return (
        <View style={styles.conainer}>
         <Text>{text}</Text>   
         <Button title="click" onPress={()=>setText("Thank you ")}/>
        </View>
    );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container : {
      flex : 1,
      justifyContent : 'center',
      alignItems : 'center',
      
  }  
})
export default TryBtn;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? You want to change the language for that specific text like only thank you in Chinese and complete app is in English or you want to translate the updated new state to the specific language that is set globally for the app.

Comment: Hey Prince Mittal , I want  that the language for that specific text like thank you in Chinese . I am translating my app into Chinese of the text part . But i notice ,it can't work when use useState ..

Comment: Okay, but where are you translating the data. As I can't see any translation-specific code here for i18n.

Comment: my bad... I have already reedit the code ,you should be able to see now ,thank you so much friend !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to implement the translation here you can do it the same way as you are doing for the initial state. Create the key-value pairs for "Thank you" text in your translations files and then translate the data before setting the state as given below

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View,Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import i18n from './../translations/i18n';

function TryBtn(props) {
    const[text,setText] =useState(i18n.t('user_detail.click_me'));
    return (
        <View style={styles.conainer}>
         <Text>{text}</Text>   
         <Button title="click" onPress={()=>setText(i18n.t("user_detail.thank_you"))}/>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Hey friend ,no ,it won't work .. I just found out the way to make it work by accidently ,you need to change 'useState({i18n.t('user_detail.click_me')})' to "useState(i18n.t('user_detail.click_me'))" and it will work . But still thank you very much for your tips!! Best !!

Comment: The syntactical error I didn't get that at the first glance. I will update that in the answer for the initial state.

Answer (score 1):

The correct format when using i18next is:

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

function AddButton({appID, selectedUser}){
    const { t } = useTranslation();
    const [yourText, setYourText] = useState(t('translation.identifier'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View,Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import i18n from './../translations/i18n';

function TryBtn(props) {
    const[text,setText] =useState(user_detail.click_me);
   ...
    setText('not.user_detail.click_me')
    return (
        <View style={styles.conainer}>
         <Text>{text}</Text>   
         <Button title="click" onPress={i18n.t(text)}/>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).